# In-app integration for alternative billing with user choice

Tags: java, android

```
ImmutableList<ProductDetailsParams> productDetailsParamsList =
ImmutableList.of(
    ProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
         // retrieve a value for "productDetails" by calling queryProductDetailsAsync()
        .setProductDetails(productDetails)
        // For one-time products, "setOfferToken" method shouldn't be called.
        // For subscriptions, to get an offer token, call
        // ProductDetails.subscriptionOfferDetails() for a list of offers
        // that are available to the user.
        .setOfferToken(selectedOfferToken)
        .build()
);

 BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
.setProductDetailsParamsList(productDetailsParamsList)
.build();

BillingResult billingResult = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, 
billingFlowParams);
```

How to get the productDetails here?  I am trying to integrate alternate payment method with google play billing, but i am unable to get good resources.

Answer (score 0):

Try This one if u wanna product details

```
List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<>(); // List of product IDs or SKUs
skuList.add("product_id_here");

SkuDetailsParams.Builder params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP); // or BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS for subscriptions

billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(), new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSkuDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
        if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && skuDetailsList != null) {
            // Process the retrieved SkuDetails list
            for (SkuDetails skuDetails : skuDetailsList) {
                String productId = skuDetails.getSku();
                String price = skuDetails.getPrice();
                // You can retrieve other details as needed
                // Here, you can build your ProductDetails object using the retrieved information
                ProductDetails productDetails = new ProductDetails(productId, price, ...);
                // Now, you can use the productDetails object in your billing flow
                // Make sure to handle any errors appropriately
            }
        } else {
            // Handle any errors or failure in retrieving SKU details
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please guide me about user choice in app payment, I am unable to perform userchoice billing also docs are very unclear too

Comment: i use google play billing method , u can see in there official website and if u wanna do other method then use third party billing procedure i have less information about third party , recommend for you google play billing ok